# QComboBox style for icon image in drop-down list

Tags: macos, qt, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

It is **very small** that my icon Image in drop-down of combobox.

This problem is happening on Mac.
There was no problem on Windows.

I tried various methods, but I could not solve it.
Please tell me what is wrong.

Simplify:

```
QComboBox* combobox = new QComboBox(ui.parentWidget);
combobox->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
combobox->setIconSize(QSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

QString name = "testImage";
QString path = "~/testImage";
combobox->addItem(QIcon(path), "", name);
```

setStyleSheet() may be bad, but it couldn't be fixed by rewriting.

List of things to try:

enlarge the image itself

write stylesheet width, min-width, implicitWidth and fillmode

setSizePolicy()

setSizeAdjustPolicy()

setPalette()

setSize() for pixmap

Comment: Setting icon size with absolute values is not reliable. I assume that your Mac just has a higher resolution than your Windows. (I just ignore the role which High-DPI management might play.) Have a look for [`QStyle::pixelMetric()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#pixelMetric). Using this, you might get better results for reasonable sizes.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that didn't solve my problem.